Flutter(Xcode 16) -CardinalMobile.framework & PPRiskMagnes contains BitCode
My Flutter app used plugin flutter_braintree 4.0.0. It used to work (Xcode 15) - I loaded the update to the Test Flight. But I upgraded to Xcode 16.
Now when I try to post an update to Test Flight I get an error:

PPRiskMagnes & CardinalMobile framework  have bitcode

How can I fix this?


This known issue helped me, you need to strip the bitcode in your Podfile.
https://discuss.bitrise.io/t/xcode-16-known-issues/24484

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

used a temporary solution - added to POD file
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    end

    bitcode_strip_path = `xcrun --find bitcode_strip`.chop!

    def strip_bitcode_from_framework(bitcode_strip_path, framework_relative_path)
      framework_path = File.join(Dir.pwd, framework_relative_path)
      command = "#{bitcode_strip_path} #{framework_path} -r -o #{framework_path}"
      puts "Stripping bitcode: #{command}"
      system(command)
    end

    framework_paths = [
      "Pods/Braintree/Frameworks/XCFrameworks/CardinalMobile.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/CardinalMobile.framework/CardinalMobile",
      "Pods/Braintree/Frameworks/XCFrameworks/CardinalMobile.xcframework/ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator/CardinalMobile.framework/CardinalMobile",
      "Pods/Braintree/Frameworks/XCFrameworks/PPRiskMagnes.xcframework/ios-arm64/PPRiskMagnes.framework/PPRiskMagnes",
      "Pods/Braintree/Frameworks/XCFrameworks/PPRiskMagnes.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/PPRiskMagnes.framework/PPRiskMagnes"
    ]

    framework_paths.each do |framework_relative_path|
      strip_bitcode_from_framework(bitcode_strip_path, framework_relative_path)
    end
  end


this worked for me (im guessing its specifically because of braintree). did you also get the upload symbols failed warnings?

yes - I have this message
